# Can I add a note to Key Vault Secrets or Keys

Tags: azure-keyvault

My developers named secrets and keys in KeyVault in such a way that you cannot determine what the key is for. I am torn between trying to have them follow our naming standards and just keeping an eternal document. Dislike unnecessary documentation. Wished there was a note field in key or secrets so I can add something there, but looks like there is not. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, I think you could use [`Secret tags`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/about-keys-secrets-and-certificates#secret-tags) and [`Key tags`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/about-keys-secrets-and-certificates#key-tags) in your keyvault.

Navigate to your keyvault in the portal -> Keys/Secrets -> select a key/secret -> set the `Tags`, then it will be like below.

[image]

Comment: Joy, thank you very much! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @JoyWang - Any idea how to remove the secret tags? Even after creating a new version, I don't see those tags getting removed.